# Google custom search autocomplete texts alignation

Tags: html, css, google-custom-search

Google custom search linked into this website http://debug.a0001.net/ returns autocomplete results aligned to extreme left. I want it to appear in line with search-box and search-results. [Open website and in the search box type T]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline-style `left:0` from the table having class `.gstl_50 gssb_c`

Or add the following CSS:

```
table.gstl_50.gssb_c {
    left: initial !important;
}
```